# MYSQL full text search numbers and character being ignored?

Tags: mysql

I"m trying to do a full text search, the database I'm querying has a lot of LCD screen sizes. Eg. 32". 
I need to do a full text search as a search phrase can be complex, we started with a LIKE comparison but it didn't cut it.

Heres what we've got.

```
SELECT stock_items.name AS si_name,
       stock_makes.name AS sm_name,
       stock_items.id AS si_id
FROM stock_items
LEFT JOIN stock_makes ON stock_items.make = stock_makes.id
WHERE MATCH (stock_items.name,
             stock_makes.name) AGAINST ('+32"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND stock_items.deleted != 1
```

With this search we get 0 results. Although 32" Appears multiple times in the fields.
We have modified the mysql config to allow us to search 3 characters or more (instead of the default four) and searches like +NEC work fine.

My guess is here that either a) full text search in mysql ignores " character or maybe the numbers.

I don't have any control over the database data unfortunately or I'd replace the double quotes with something else. 
Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL ignore cirtain characters when indexing, " is one of them I presume.
There are few ways to change the default character settings as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

- Modify the MySQL source: In myisam/ftdefs.h, see the true_word_char() and misc_word_char() macros. Add '-' to one of those macros and recompile MySQL.
- Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish letters and numbers from other characters. . You can edit the contents of the  array in one of the character set XML files to specify that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for your FULLTEXT indexes.
- Add a new collation for the character set used by the indexed columns, and alter the columns to use that collation.

I used the second approach and that worked for us. [The provided page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) has a detailed example in the comments at the end of the page (comment by John Navratil).

In any case you need to rebuild the index after you changed settings: 
`REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK;`

Comment: Recompiling isn't an option for us unfortunately or we'd just do that . Can you give any insight into how the second one is done, following the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/character-arrays.html suggests that in fact the directory /sql/share/charsets/ is actually a source file directory... so not sure where to edit the charsets ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Modifying charset file doesn't require compilation. There is a detailed example here in the comments after the article: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: I'm using UTF8, there isn't a UTF8.xml in the charsets folder.
Looking in the index.xml file in the charsets folder there is a flag against utf8 <flag>compiled</flag> so guessing it doesn't have a charset folder. Any other options besides changing the charset of the table or recompiling mysql ?

Comment: It looks like you can't do it for UTF8 without recompile. See some more info here: http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=91

Comment: Thanks for your help, looks like MYSQL full text search isn't going to work for me. Going to look at Apache Solr instead. WIll mark yours as the answer though since it's lead me to this.